# CSS3 animations breaking fixed positioning when page scrolled

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-animations

I'm having trouble trying to figure out why chrome (which makes the fixed header completely disappear, Firefox keeps it there but lets absolutely positioned elements flow over the fixed element, I've averted the problem using opacity:.99, but I still wracks my mind how that does anything to fix it.

http://www.rickpascua.cu.cc/newsite-snazzy/index.html <--- problem page.

Comment: Nothing else on this page worked for me, but setting the element's opacity to 0.99 fixed my problem like magic.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't actually know why the CSS animation is breaking the layout. In my testing, with the animations running, having `overflow:hidden;z-index` on the header was causing it to lose fixed positioning! However, I do have an answer.

To begin with, remove

```
overflow:hidden;
visibility:visible;
z-index:99;
```

from the fixed position header element `<div id="header">`.

However with those 3 properties removed, the `<div id="slide-contain"/>` will still overlap! This is because of the implicit stacking context layering, see the 7 layers in the [CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#The_third_dimension](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#The_third_dimension.E2.80.94z-index) article.

The unwanted overlap occurs because `position:relative` has been set on the `<div id="slide-contain"/>` (which is a descendent of the `<div id="wrapper"/>`) but there is **no `z-index`** on that element. I realise that the relative positioning was added because you want to absolutely position some child elements inside.

Therefore the `<div id="slide-contain"/>` element is on the same Z-plane as every other element without a z-index on the page, which includes the fixed header. Both elements are at *Level 6 - Positioned descendants with the stack level set as auto or (zero)*, according to the linked article and stacking defaults to the *order in which the elements appear on the DOM*, so the `<div id="slide-contain"/>` is rendered over `.

So a `z-index:1` is required on the header to always render the header on top. It just needs to be greater than 0, so change `z-index:99` to `z-index:1`

An alternate solution would be to supply a **negative** `z-index` (and `position:relative`) on the following sibling `<div id="wrapper"/>`.

You might think that adding a negative `z-index` on the `<div id="slide-contain"/>` would be enough but it would need duplicating to the element ancestors, otherwise the `<div id="slide-contain"/>` would be pushed behind its parent.

Comment: Ahh much thanks, looking back it seems kind of stupid that I wouldn't try a z-index on the absolutely position element, I thought a single z-index on my fixed element covered it, always learning!

Comment: Happy to help :-) I'm still actually trying to create a simple test case for this issue as I am also confused as to why the animation breaks the layout.

Answer (score 4):

Set following CSS to the disappear element

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform        : translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

The `transform` attribute `translated3d` doesn't exist. `translate3d` does, and should resolve fixed positioning with animated elements on the same page.

Comment: I believe this is because translate3d is a hardware-accelerated property; I believe any hardware-accelerated property would "fix" the issue. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: user @jacob points out that this is a wrong approach that can negatively impact performance. Any property that forces hardware acceleration will do the trick, but instead of applying this rule globally, try applying this rule to the elements that break only.**

just encountered a similar issue when combining animate.css with foundation by zurb.

the solution i came up with based on Ryan Wu's answer

```
* {
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

It worked for my problem (fixed elements losing padding/borders and other nasties during animation)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed to fix a weird Chrome (webkit) bug :-)

Comment: @kipusoep might be wise to set it only on the elements you need. i ran into problems with this approach with some animations.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on those issues in you original comment?

Comment: I believe this is because backface-visibility is a hardware-accelerated property; I believe any hardware-accelerated property would "fix" the issue. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Also, beware: Forcing hardware-acceleration on every element ~will~can negatively impact performance, especially on mobiles.

Comment: @jacob you are 100% correct. It can also lead to other bugs. i should probably delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this bug happens because the container's animation is offloaded to the GPU; however, the fixed-positioning takes the descendant out of the flow, so it is not offloaded along with the container. And then the fixed-position element is incorrectly composited. Adding any hardware-accelerated property (ex `translate3d`) to the fixed-positioned element appears to "fix" the problem (I believe because it is then also offloaded to the GPU, avoiding the issue during compositing).

Ex

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container {
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-name: some-animation;
}

.fixed {
  /* transform: translateX(-200%); */
  transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 10rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(../assets/logo.png) center no-repeat,url(../assets/header2.jpg) bottom center;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
z-index: 99;
```

try this one it will work.

but there is also issue with your inner html in header div you are using float div so you should also use clear class with them if you want to use overflow:hidden or auto.

Comment: I have a specified height So there really isn't a need for a clear-fix and overflow:hidden is because animations have edges that overflow but arent visible.  I tried the code but the problem persists.