# Fixed position lost with overflow hidden and CSS3 animation

Tags: css, webkit, css-position, css-animations

Following on from [CSS3 animations breaking fixed positioning when page scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563612/css3-animations-breaking-fixed-positioning-when-page-scrolled) I have created a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/C95nq/) (webkit only). Code is copied below also.

What I want is a fixed header and relatively positioned content. The reason the content is relatively positioned is because there are certain elements that are absolutely positioned inside the paragraph; although I've omitted them from this example.

Of course adding `position:relative` to the `<p>` (without a `z-index`) causes the content to be stacked on top of the header which is not desired. i.e. if the CSS is just

```
#header {
  background-color:#f00;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  position:fixed;
}

p {
  width:100px;
  padding-top:50px;
  position:relative;
}
```

then the text is visible over the header. So we add a `z-index:1` to the header to fix that. However, this still doesn't address the problem of the spinning image overflowing the header. I would have thought a simple `overflow:hidden` on the header would work. It seems to until the page is scrolled, whereupon the *fixed* header also scrolls.

It seems to be the presence of `z:index` and `overflow:hidden`, although `auto` and `scroll` also break the layout and I want to know **why?**

Instead of `z-index:1` on the header I **could** use a `z-index:-1` on the `<p>` but that still doesn't explain why the combination of `z:index`, `overflow` and the CSS3 animation causes the fixed header to scroll.

Lastly (and of course) removing the awful spinning animation makes the header fixed as expected. Please note, that I wouldn't ever have that animation on a page, it's just there to highlight the problem :-)

Code showing the problem (only for webkit browsers)

#### HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="spinner"></div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

#### CSS

```
body, p {
  margin:0;
}

#header {
  background-color:#f00;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#spinner {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/40/40/abstract/1/);
  height:44px;
  width:44px;
  margin:2px 0 0 2px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg)}
  50% {-webkit-transform:rotate(720deg)}
  100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(1440deg)}
}

p {
  width:100px;
  padding-top:50px;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: You can simulate a z-index by simply moving your div to after your paragraph. As long as you position it to fixed to where you want it to be, and remove the z-index, it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/C95nq/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform : translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

to the fixed element on the page. Its seems animations require to be told in which perspective they should exist, setting 3d to 0 would imply 2d.

Comment: Ah, do you have any articles as reference on that? Having just tested the original demo again, it now seems to be working OK in Chrome 26, without any additional CSS. Maybe it was a bug that's now fixed. Which browser are you using?

Comment: The same Chrome 26, my case scenario is Bootstrap navbar becomes detached when I have an animated element that is hidden and shown with JS.

Comment: "adding ... to the fixed element on the page" - thanks!! Had it on a parent element and lost the fixed-ness.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a weird behaviour and probably a webkit bug but I managed to fix the problem by nesting an extra div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="fix">
        <div id="spinner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
  background-color:#f00;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
}
#fix{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C95nq/23/

For whatever reason that combination of properties breaks but **move the overflow:hidden to its own div seems to fix the issue.**