# CSS 'bottom' position not working in Firefox only

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

I'm attempting to position these icons to the bottom left of my page using CSS to align them. It works perfectly in all browser but Firefox. I've tried many things but cannot get it to work. You can check out the [fiddle script](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8f9/2325/) and though it looks bad, you can see the icons are in fact positioned in the correct spot. When you load the [actual webpage](http://box.endurehosting.com/) in Firefox, you can see the icons are actually more in the middle of the page. Can anyone tell me what's going on? I've tried rearranging the code many different ways and changing the position field but to no avail. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!--Blacklist-->
<?php
$file = file('blacklist.txt');
foreach ($file as $line)
{
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $line) {
        die;
    }
}
?>

<!--IP Logger-->
<?php
    if (getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") != "192.168.1.1")
    {
        $filename = "iplog.txt" ; 

        $file = file($filename); 
        $file = array_unique($file); 

        $fd = fopen ($filename , "r"); 
        $fstring = fread ($fd , filesize ($filename)) ; 
        fclose($fd); 
        $fd = fopen ($filename , "w"); 
        $fcounted = $fstring."\n".getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); 
        $fout= fwrite ($fd , $fcounted );
        fclose($fd);
    }
?>

<!--Hit Counter-->
<?php
    if (getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") != "192.168.1.1")
    {
        $datei = fopen("counter.txt","r");
        $count = fgets($datei, 1000);
        fclose($datei);
        $count=$count + 1 ;
        $datei = fopen("counter.txt","w");
        fwrite($datei, $count);
        fclose($datei);
}
?>

<title>Endure Box</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/images/favicon.ico">

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.interactive_bg.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="tooltip/tooltipscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tooltip/tooltipstyle.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<!--Disable Right Clicks-->
<script language="javascript">
    document.onmousedown = disableclick;
    function disableclick(event) 
    {
        if (event.button == 2) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<!--View-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Page').fadeIn(500).removeClass('hidden');
    resize();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    resize();
};

function resize(){
    if ($(window).width() < 800)
    {
        $("#Page").removeClass("Normal");
        $("#Page").addClass("Small");
        $("#IconBar").removeClass("Normal");
        $("#IconBar").addClass("Small");
    }

    if ($(window).width() > 800)
    {
        $("#Page").removeClass("Small");
        $("#Page").addClass("Normal");
        $("#IconBar").removeClass("Small");
        $("#IconBar").addClass("Normal");
    }
}
</script>

<!--Animations-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Page").animate({opacity: 1}, 800);
        $("#IconBar").animate({opacity: 1}, 850);

        $("#hid").change(function() {
            if(document.getElementById("hid").value)
            {
                $('#Form').fadeIn(500).removeClass('hidden');
                $('#upload_button').removeClass('hidden');
                $("#upload_button").animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#Form').fadeOut(500).addClass('hidden');
                $('#upload_button').addClass('hidden');
                $("#upload_button").animate({opacity: 0}, 0);
            }
         });  

        $(".Box").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity: .95, height: 235, width: 235}, 150);
            $("#OpenText").stop().animate({opacity: .85}, 400);
        });
        $(".Box").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity: .85, height: 220, width: 220}, 150);
            $("#OpenText").stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
        });

        $(".Icons").hover(function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1, height: 35, width: 35}, 100);
        }, function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity: .95, height: 32, width: 32}, 100);
        });
    });

function uploadstatus(uploading){
        if (uploading)
        {
            $("#choosefile").addClass("hidden");
            $("#Loading").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#upload_button").addClass("hidden");
            $("#upload_button").animate({opacity: 1}, 350);
            $("#Form").animate({opacity: 0}, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#Loading").addClass("hidden");
            $("#upload_button").animate({opacity: 0}, 0);
            $("#upload_button").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#choosefile").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    }
</script>

<!--Body-->
<body oncontextmenu="return false">

<!--Input Parser-->
<script language="javascript">
String.prototype.ucfirst = function()
{
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substr(1);
}

$("document").ready(function(){ 
    $("#hid").change(function() {
        <!--Get File Name-->
        var path = document.getElementById("hid").value;
        var fileName = "" + path.match(/[^\/\\]+$/);

        <!--Get Title-->
        var titlelength = fileName.indexOf('.');
        var truncatedtitle = fileName.substring(0, titlelength).ucfirst();;
        document.getElementById('Title').value = truncatedtitle;
    });  
});
</script>

<!--Cleanup-->
<script language="javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#hid").change(function() {
        if (document.getElementById("SuccessText") || document.getElementById("ErrorText") || document.getElementById("NameText"))
        {
            if (document.getElementById('SuccessText'))
            {
                var SuccessText = document.getElementById('SuccessText');
                SuccessText.parentNode.removeChild(SuccessText);
            }

            if (document.getElementById('NameText'))
            {
                var NameText = document.getElementById('NameText');
                NameText.parentNode.removeChild(NameText);
            }

            if (document.getElementById('ErrorText'))
            {
                var ErrorText = document.getElementById('ErrorText');
                ErrorText.parentNode.removeChild(ErrorText);
            }   
        }
    });  
});
</script>       

<!--Body-->
<div class="bg" data-ibg-bg="/images/background.jpg">

<div class="display" id="Page" style="opacity:0;" align="center">
</br></br></br>
<img src="/images/logo.png">
</br></br></br>
<a href="/contents/public/"><img style="opacity:.8;cursor:default" src="/images/box.png" class="Box" id="Box"></a>
</br></br>
<p class="OpenText" id="OpenText" style="opacity:0;cursor:default">Open the box</p>
</br>


<!--Form-->
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="choosefile">
<div id="doit">
<img src="images/choose_file.png"/>
</div>

<input id="hid" name="file" type="file" size=1></div>
</br>
<img src="images/loading.gif" id="Loading" class="hidden" width="85" height="85">

<div class="FormText hidden" id="Form" style="cursor:default">

File Name:
</br>
<input class="InfoText" type="text" id="Title" name="Title" value="" size="30">
</br></br>
Private:
</br>
<select class="InfoText" id="Private" name="Private" style="width:150px">
  <option value="Public">Public</option>
  <option value="Private">Private</option>
</select>
</br></br>
<input type="image" src="/images/upload_button.png" id="upload_button" value="Submit" class="hotspot hidden" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Your IP is <?php echo getenv(REMOTE_ADDR); ?>');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onclick="uploadstatus(true);"/> 
</br>
</div>
</form>

<!--Upload-->
<?php

if ($_POST)
    {           
if (strpos(($_FILES["file"]["name"]), 'php') == TRUE || strpos(($_FILES["file"]["name"]), 'jsp') == TRUE)
        {
            echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>Filetype Banned!</p>";            
        }
        else
        {
        $path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ($_POST['Private'] == "Private")
            {
                if (!file_exists('contents/private/' . getenv(REMOTE_ADDR)))
                {
                    mkdir('contents/private/' . getenv(REMOTE_ADDR), 0777, true);
                }
                    $folder = "contents/private/" . getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
            }
        else
        {
            $folder = "contents/public/";
        }

        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = $_POST['Title'] . '.' . end($temp);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folder . '/' . $newfilename);
        $uploadStatus = true;
        }
    }

if ($uploadStatus)
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>Upload Failed!</p>";

                if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 1)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>File exceeds PHP upload limit (4 GB)</p>";
                    }
                else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 2)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>File exceeds HTML upload limit (4 GB)</p>";
                    }
                else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 3)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>The file was only partially uploaded (network interruption?)</p>";
                    }
                else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 4)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>No file was selected!</p>";
                    }
                else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 6)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>The temporary folder is missing! Contact administrator!</p>";
                    }
                else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 7)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>Failed to write file to disk (Permission error?)</p>";
                    }
                else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 8)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='ErrorText' id='ErrorText'>A PHP extension has stopped the upload!</p>";
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'uploadstatus(false); ', '</script>';

                echo "<p class='SuccessText' id='SuccessText'>Upload Successful!</p>";          

                echo "<p class='FileText' id='NameText'>" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] ." uploaded!</p></br>";

                $ipLog="uploadlog.txt";
                $friendly_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                $file_size = $_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024 / 1024 . " MB";
                $register_globals = (bool) ini_get('register_gobals'); 
                $ip = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
                $date = date ('m-d-Y H:i:s');
                $log = fopen("$ipLog", "a+"); 

                if (preg_match("/\bhtm\b/i", $ipLog) || preg_match("/\bhtml\b/i", $ipLog))  
                    { 
                        fputs($log, "File: $friendly_name | Size: $file_size | IP Address: $ip | Date Uploaded: $date <br>"); 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        fputs($log, "File: $friendly_name | Size: $file_size | IP Address: $ip | Date Uploaded: $date \n"); 
                    }

                fclose($log);

                $uploadStatus = false;
        }
    }
?>

</div>



</div>

<!--Background Resize Manager-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".bg").interactive_bg();
    $(window).resize(function(){$(".bg > .ibg-bg").css({width: $(window).outerWidth(),height: $(window).outerHeight()})})
</script>

</body>
<!--Icons-->
<div id="IconBar" style="opacity:0;">

<img src="/images/info.png" class="hotspot Icons" onmouseover="tooltip.show('We respect your privacy, but we do not hold any responsibilty for any damages uploaded to the box. If there is an issue with any content, including personal and copyright complaints, please feel free to email me for corrections.');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();"; 

style="position:fixed; 
float:left; 
left:12px; 
bottom:6px;
z-index:1;">

<a href="/contents/private/index.php?dir=<?php echo getenv(REMOTE_ADDR); ?>"><img src="/images/lock.png" class="hotspot Icons" onmouseover="tooltip.show('View your private files assciated with: <?php echo getenv(REMOTE_ADDR); ?>');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();";

style="position:fixed; 
float:left; 
left:54px; 
bottom:6px;
z-index:1;">
</a>

<a href="http://box.endurehosting.com/printscreensharp/PrintScreen%23.exe"><img src="/images/printscreensharp.png" class="hotspot Icons"  onmouseover="tooltip.show('Download the latest version of PrintScreen#, the automatic screensnapper');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();";

style="position:fixed; 
float:left; 
left:96px; 
bottom:6px;
z-index:1;">
</a>

<a href="http://helpdesk.endurehosting.com/"><img src="/images/email.png" class="hotspot Icons"  onmouseover="tooltip.show('If you have any suggestions, questions, or comments, feel free to shoot me an email at Kinlough@EndureMail.com or use our helpdesk');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();";

style="position:fixed; 
float:left; 
left:138px; 
bottom:6px;
z-index:1;">
</a>

<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=BQLLXSL2AMZS8"><img src="/images/donate.png" class="hotspot Icons"  onmouseover="tooltip.show('Buy me a coffee!');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();";

style="position:fixed; 
float:left; 
left:180px; 
bottom:6px;
z-index:1;">
</a>

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Tips: 1. Your site loads nearly 3MB.  That's pretty large, I'd suggest shrinking your assets, particularly your background image which is over 1.5MB alone (should be no reason it's more than 250k).  2. Inline styles are a royal pain to maintain over time, I'd strongly recommend using classes / ID's and putting the styles into a stylesheet.  3. `<br>` tags stink.  Change to `<p>` tags and use styles to get the desired layout.  4. Per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440604/css-position-fixed-acting-like-absolute-in-firefox the issue is `transform` on the parent.

Comment: The fiddle you linked to is working in Firefox. The code you've provided doesn't show anything if I put it in a fiddle (not even broken image icons for some reason). You need to provide enough code in the question itself to reproduce the issue. Linking to your live site is insufficient since that will change as soon as you fix the problem and won't be visible to future visitors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - "position: fixed" acting like "absolute" in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440604/css-position-fixed-acting-like-absolute-in-firefox)

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into minimalizing my code. I recently changed the background and forgot to downscale it. As for the code I provided, I didn't actually want to include it here, but it was making me provide code and I was having formatting issues and cut some of it out. Must have messed something up along the way. I didn't consider about other people visiting this page in the future, I'll be sure to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove the `-moz-transform: scale(1);` on the `.Normal` class, it appears like it does in Chrome on FireFox:

```
.Normal {
    zoom: 1;
    /*-moz-transform: scale(1);*/
}
```

That line can be found in the file: http://box.endurehosting.com/css/style.css

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uw8f9/2326/

Comment: This is a dupe.  I'd recommend voting to close as such, rather than answering.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Feel kinda silly for not realizing that but I was borrowing that code from somewhere and wasn't sure what it did exactly and decided to include it anyway.

Comment: You could be right there, but I haven't yet managed to get the solution for the proposed dupe to fix Syllith's problem, and there doesn't seem to be a `backface-visibility` in their code that I've found yet.