# html/css parallax with fixed navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the code below that need some help with fixed position.  Especially involving perspective and transform.  When i use the parallax effect with css (`transform:translateZ`) the navigation position (`position:fixed`) doesn't apply.  I'm hoping someone could help me point out how to have the navigation fixed top when scrolled and also keep the parallax effect.

html:

```
  <div class="parallax-layer parallax-slider">
     <div id="slider">
        <img src="img/image/background.png">
     </div>
  </div>

  <div id="nav-top"></div>

  <div class="parallax-layer parallax-body">
     <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">first item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">third item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">forth item</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="main">
           <div id="content">
           content goes here
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <footer></footer>
```

css:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
}
.parallax {
    perspective: 1700px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y; auto;
}
.parallax-layer {
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.parallax-slider {
    transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(1.2,1.287);
}
.parallax-body {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
}
#nav-top {
    top:0;
}
#nav.fix {
    position: fixed !important;
    top:0;
}
#nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1080px;
    background-color: rgba(39,39,39,1);
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    margin-top=0;
}
#slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#slider img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    right: 0;
}
#main-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}
#main {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $("#nav-top").offset().top;
    console.log(div_top);
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#nav').addClass('fix');
    } else {
        $('#nav').removeClass('fix');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Look into this so thread, it might help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563612/css3-animations-breaking-fixed-positioning-when-page-scrolled

Answer (score 0):

For parallax effect you can also use background-attachment: fixed; and put your image in background-image:url("your img path");